# Firebase churn predictions being logged after the actual churn took place

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-predictions

I am trying to see how accurate firebase predictions are. I have exported firebase predictions and analytics events to BigQuery.
In order to test the performance of predictions, I wrote a query which harvests predictions for the `churn` event, then joined that with `app_remove` events from analytics.
The problem was that **for many, many users, the `app_remove` event had been logged before the prediction date!** As if google waited for the user to churn, then place the prediction of churn in the table. Am I missing something?

here is my code:

```
SELECT
    b.day AS prediction_day,
    b.user_id,
    c.day AS churn_day
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(day) AS day,
        user_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(u.prediction_time AS DATE) AS day,
            u.user_id,
            p.id,
            p.probability,
            p.observed_label
        FROM
            `Predictions_table` AS u,
            u.predictions AS p
    )a
    WHERE
        a.probability > 0.2
        AND a.id = 'churn'
        AND NOT (a.user_id IS NULL OR a.user_id = '')
    GROUP BY
        user_id
)b
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MAX(day) AS day,
        user_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS DATE) AS day,
            user_id
        FROM
            `Analytics_table`
        WHERE
            event_name = 'app_remove'
            AND NOT (user_id IS NULL OR user_id = '')
    )e
    GROUP BY
        user_id

)c
ON b.user_id = c.user_id
```

Comment: So the prediction is correct. Based on what I know about how these models work, it needs time to collect behavioural data and it needs time to reach a certain confidence threshold. So either the app_remove events are happening before the model has enough information to possibly predict that it will happen, or it just doesn't have enough data overall.

Comment: @windowsill I guess I expected Google to not place a user in the predictions table if they had already removed the app.